# Properties of solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem $y'' = - y$ with $y(0) = 0$, $y'(0) = 1$, $0 \leq x \le \pi$.  Without solving the differential equation, show that $y$ is symmetric about $m$, where $y'(m) = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

By iterating on $y''=-y$, we see that $y$ is infinitely differentiable. Expand $y(m+x)$ around $m$:
$$
y(m+x)=y(m)+y'(m)x+\frac{y''(m)}{2}x^2+\frac{y'''(m)}{3!}x^3+\ldots
$$
Because $y'(m)=0$ and $y''=-y$, all the derivatives with odd orders vanish. This implies $y(m+x)=y(m-x)$.

Comment: Thank you Kim. But how do we get the assurance that $y$ is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: $y''=-y$ so $y'''=-y'$ and $y^{(4)}=-y''=y$. You can continue this indefinitely. Kim out (to bed!).

Answer (score 1):

The initial value problem
$$
y''=-y,\quad y(m)=y_0,\,\, y'(m)=0,\qquad (\star)
$$
enjoys uniqueness. Let $\psi$ be a solution and set $\varphi(x)=\psi(2m-x)$. Clearly
$$
\varphi''(x)=\psi''(2m-x)=-\psi(2m-x)=-\varphi(x),\\ \varphi(m)=\psi(2m-m)=\psi(m)=y_0,\\ \varphi'(m)=-\psi(2m-m)=\psi(m)=0.
$$
Thus $\varphi$ satisfies $(\star)$ as well, and hence $\varphi\equiv\psi$, due to uniqueness.

Comment: Superb. Thank you Yiorgos. The logic is very nice.